# Incrementing letters in string - treating char as int without using .charCodeAt(0)

Tags: javascript

Here is my assignment:

> Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a).

Now I've done this type of thing in my C lessons using some fancy modulo 26 business and a lot of subtraction and offsetting of ASCII values.

Is it going to take even more lines in JavaScript (since instead of treating a char as an int I have to use `fromCharCode` and `charCodeAt`), or does JavaScript have some shortcuts for this task?

Comment: This is your assignment, what have u tried so far

Comment: Show us your attempt at solving this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this:-

```
String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + 1)
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pitaj/3F5Qt/)

Comment: That's what I got. Looks like that's the path I'll have to take. Thanks.

Comment: You still should pass the argument to `charCodeAt` even when `undefined` defaults to zero.

Comment: Note that if you pass in 'Z' or 'z' it will "break": http://jsfiddle.net/3uj042gg/